# Pass value from Handlebars template to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, templates, handlebars.js

I would like to pass the object from Handlebars template to my Javascript code to parse it. After it is parsed, I'd like it displayed in the template. Is it possible to do something like this?

**JSON**

```
{users: [
    {name: "Frank", lastname: "Franklin", domain: "gmail"},
    {name: "Bob", lastname: "Brandy", domain: "yahoo"},
    {name: "Rob", lastname: "Rems", domain: "msn"}
]};
```

**1. Pass the "user" object from template to Javascript, and in Javascript build the new object based on the JSON input**

***Users.html***

```
{{#each users}}
     <li>
       <!-- How to pass a single User here? -->
       <!-- {{email}} would be returned from Javascript as a new value -->
       <a href="{{{buildEmail user}}}" target="_blank">{{email}}</a>
     </li>
{{/each}}
```

**2. Parse the user in Javascript, return email object**

**EmailParser.js**

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('buildEmail',
    function(user, options) {
        var firstname = user.firstname;
        var lastname = user.lastname;
        var domain = user.domain;

        return firstname + "." + lastname + "@" + domain + ".com";
    });
```

And I want in my HTML template to be displayed, for every user: `firstname.lastname@domain.com` (with real values from JSON).

### The problem

The problem is that the JSON attributes like "user.firstname" and "user.lastname" are unknown in Javascript when I try do to it like that. Is there a way to pass a JSON from template to Javascript, parse it there, and return a new object to display?

Comment: I handle such situations by passing the JSON data as value of a hidden input element. Then, using js/jquery, you can pick this JSON data, parse it and access its properties.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Could you please show me with an example? What kind of hidden input element, and how do you then access a JSON?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Because the Users are only part of a much bigger JSON, so I would need to store just the "Users" part somewhere, and acces it from Javascript somehow.

Comment: I have little knowledge of handlebars. I use Jade myself. But have you tried using this - {{{buildEmail this}}} instead of {{{buildEmail user}}} ?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj is correct, it must be `{{buildEmail this}}` or `{{buildEmail .}}`. Also, there is no `user.firstname`, only `user.name`.